# Ubuntu 17 apt, ping... suddenly started using ipv6, connections failing

Tags: networking, dns

Tried on MATE 17.10, Xubuntu 17.10, (and 18.04) This is affecting only some hostnames. Compare these pings to ubuntu and a ping to google:

```
ping -c1 ubuntu.com
PING ubuntu.com (91.189.94.40) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ovinnik.canonical.com (91.189.94.40): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=154 ms
....
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms

ping -c1 google.com
PING google.com(sea15s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400a:806::200e)) 56 data bytes
....
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

This occurs with DNS set to any of 9.9.9.9,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 or my ISP's DNS.

I see that many people disable IPv6. I'm not sure I want to do that. I am hoping for an explanation of this strange occurrence and for a configuration fix.

Also, without a configuration adjustment, I won't be able to update to any release updates.

Thanks.

EDIT
After Soren's comment suggesting that if my ISP does not support IPv6 then my concern for keeping IPv6 is unneccessary, I felt ok about disabling IPv6. So....

[disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 16+](https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-linuxubuntu)

And now apt and ping ... are working as expected. However I am still hoping for an explanation of why this started to happen.

Comment: Do your ISP support IPv6 ? If he don't (and most don't) you have no gain of having IPv6 enabled.

Comment: I see people complaining that my ISP supports IPv6 only for business accounts so I assume that it is not supported. Thanks for the question. I will disable it and see if that helps. However, I still want to know why this has started happening.

Comment: So using this https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-linuxubuntu, I disabled IPv6 and now ping and apt work as expected.

Comment: Another wrinkle. I am visiting a friend who recently changed her ISP to one who does support IPv6.  I just found out.So there are other issues to explore. I will follow up after some investigation.